# Is there another URL link to react to discord messages?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, discord, emoji

I am trying to react discord server messages with emoji automatically. I am python code to do this:

```
import requests
import emoji
headers = {
    "authorization": token
}
em = emoji.emojize(':thumbs_up:')
r=requests.put(f"https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/{server_ID}/messages/{channel_ID}/reactions/{em}/%40me",
              headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

[The code is from here:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld5kZT2uzNs&ab_channel=VintageArtTV)
Token, channel id and server are correct.
Result is 404, which for me means the link is wrong, do I miss something ?

Checked id for channel and server twice, also token.
Tried to add urllib.parse module as you can see in following code:

```
import requests
import emoji
import urllib.parse
headers = {
    "authorization": token
}
em = emoji.emojize(':thumbs_up:')
em = urllib.parse.quote(em)
r=requests.put(f"https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/{server_ID}/messages/{channel_ID}/reactions/{em}/%40me",
              headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

because found the emoji should mess the link, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use this, with a `/` after `messages`.

```py
r=requests.put(f"https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/{server_ID}/messages/{channel_ID}/reactions/{em}/%40me",
```

Also, use the following parameters. **Note that this is only working for user accounts, not bot accounts**.

```py
import requests

url = f"https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/{channel_id}/messages/{message_id}/reactions//%40me"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': token
}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Missed to add it, so edited. Still have the error

Comment: it's fixed, let me know if that works for you

Comment: I get this {"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0}

Comment: are you using a user account or a bot account?

Comment: I am using a user account

Comment: all right, then I updated the code again ;)

Comment: it worked, and makes more sense your code, basically have to put my channel id after the channels/ and message id after messages/. would you like to send me your discord username to add you ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what you have to do. Use Stackoverflow to ask your questions I will be happy to answer them here!

Comment: i cant use discord emoji :tada: in python, i print instead :party_popper: have any idea what can i do ?

Comment: You should use the emoji Unicode yes